# How to debug GUI freezing with Google Chrome with Google Meet?

Tags: google-chrome, freeze

I have a problem with my laptop (Dell Latitude 7430 with Ubuntu 22.10). When I join a meeting with Google Meet with Chrome within 30m my whole UI freezes and only hard restart helps. The machine keeps working, the audio works, but UI is frozen completely. I guess the issue is connected to UI/accelerator drivers crashing because this does not reproduce with Firefox but Google Meet does not support video effects.

How can I find out what the problem?

Comment: Try Xorg instead of wayland.